# First Child Last Child Dom traversal not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, traversal

I am learning Javascript and encounter a strange problem that I really don't understand. I am following the Book Javascritp and Jquery by Jon Duckett. I am doing the same as described in the book but for some reason it doesn't work. According to the code the first child of ul should get a class of current but it doesn't. Can someone please help and explain whats going wrong with the code. Thanks

```js
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];

var firstItem = ul.firstChild;

firstItem.setAttribute('class', 'current');
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  width: 220px;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

.current {
  background: #84ac47;
}

#nav {
  width: 220px;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#previous {
  float: left;
}

#next {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul id='list'>
  <li class='null'>One</li>
  <li id='two'>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
  <div id="nav">
    <button id="previous">Previous</button>
    <button id="next">Next</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `firstChild` does just that, get's the first child element of another element, and in your case it's picking up the empty text node between `<ul id='list'>` and `<li class='null'>One</li>`. If you remove the spaces between these elements the code works. `<ul id='list'><li class='null'>One</li>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned a book on JavaScript and jQuery so thought I would add an alternative method if you're interested in the jQuery version:

**First**

```
$("ul#list li:first").addClass("current");
```

**Last**

```
$("ul#list li:last").addClass("current");
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm interested to learn plane javascript first as on the Internet a lot of people said that I should first learn javascriot on its own and then move on to any library and framework. Thanks again

Comment: That's understandable and agree with that approach. Just wanted to add the alternative encase it was of interest :)

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

You should try doing something like this:

```
var firstItem = ul.children[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did remove the space between parent and child and it did work. Can you explain what var firstItem = ul.children[0] will do and what's the best way to get the first child without whitespaces.